# In Excel, using OpenXML, how do you change the value of a checkbox in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an existing Excel spreadsheet that I need to start populating with data.   On the spreadsheet are some check boxes.  In C# using the OpenXML libraries I can get access to the file, add cell data, but cannot figure out how to get the check boxes.  They seem to be in the WorsheetPart.DrawingPart.WorksheetDrawing.  How do I get a reference to a checkbox and change its value?

This is the start of my method:

```
var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true);

        var sheet =
            spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>()
                .Elements<Sheet>()
                .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "The Worksheet");

        var relationshipId = sheet.Id.Value;

        var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart) spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
```

Comment: what checkbox a form or activex? you may want to iterate the OleObjects collections to get to a combobox

Comment: it is a form checkbox.  I found a collection of controls, now I am just working on identifying which checkbox is which.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?